# Create a Job Queue or Task Controller and dynamically add task to it in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, executorservice

I want to create a job queue to execute multiple tasks. but, my requirement is I should be able to add tasks to that job queue at any time and all those tasks should be executed sequentially. I searched for some solutions on the internet and found these two links:

1. [Java Thread Pool Executor Example](http://howtodoinjava.com/best-practices/java-executor-framework-tutorial-and-best-practices/)
2. [Java Executor Framework Tutorial and Best Practices](http://howtodoinjava.com/best-practices/java-executor-framework-tutorial-and-best-practices/)

But I can't use both of these solutions. Because after starting the `ExecutorService` I can't add a new task to the service. Because we know that It may throw `InterruptedException` or `ConcurrentModificationException`.

Comment: Use a `BlockingQueue` to hold runnables and keep removing and executing in a background thread?

Comment: Can you please give some example links

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a `BlockingQueue` to keep waiting in a separate thread until one or more `Runnable` show up.

```
public class Mainer {
    private static final BlockingQueue<Runnable> queue = new ArrayBlockingQueue<>(15);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Thread t = new Thread(() -> {
            while (true) {
                try {
                    queue.take().run();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        });
        t.start();

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            queue.add(() -> {
                System.out.println("Hello");
            });
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: this is what i need actually.. :)

Comment: Glad it helped.

Answer (score 4):

I think that you **should be** using an `ExecutorService`.

- It maintains a queue of tasks to be run.  You can provide your own queue if you need to.
- New tasks can be added at any time using the `submit` method.
- Futures may be obtained when submitting tasks.
- Tasks may be run one at a time, or in parallel using a pool of worker threads.
- If you use multiple threads, the various executor service implementations provide different pool management strategies.
- There are operations for draining and shutting down the service.

If you want an `ExecutorService` that will always run the tasks one at a time, make sure that you specify a thread pool with a maximum size of one thread.

> you please give some example links

The [javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html) have examples.

---

The objections that you raised are all based on incorrect information.

> 1. But I can't use both of these solution. Because after starting `ExecutorService` I can't add new task to the service.

Yes you can.  That is what `ExecutorService.submit(...)` does.

> 2. Because we know that it may throw `InterruptedException` ...

It will only throw `InterruptedException` if your application does something to cause that to happen; e.g. shutting down the `ExecutorService` using `shutdownNow()`.  (If you don't want that, you can use `shutdown()` instead, or simply not shut down the executor at all.  Refer to the javadocs for more details.)

Anyway, your code can deal with the exception, as the code in the [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41313060/139985) does ... albeit that it handles it in a way that you *shouldn't* do in production code.  (Printing a stacktrace to standard output is a bad idea.  And ignoring an `InterruptedException` could be wrong thing, in some contexts.)

> 3. ... or `ConcurrentModificationException`.

AFAIK, the only scenario where an `ExecutorService` can throw `ConcurrentModificationException` is if you are using a custom `Queue` class that isn't implemented properly.

Answer (score 0):

Adding implementation to [Stephen answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41312981/create-a-job-queue-or-task-controller-and-dynamically-add-task-to-it-in-java/41313303#41313303)

```
public class MyController {
    ExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
    Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(MyController.class.getName());

    //POST
    public void addTask(String taskId){
        Runnable task = createTask(taskId);
        executor.submit(task);
    }

    public void shutdown(){
        executor.shutdown();
    }

    private Runnable createTask(String taskId) {
        return new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    taskId.toString();
                    //your task
                }catch (Exception e){
                    logger.log(Level.SEVERE,"error executing task"+taskId);
                }
            }
        };
    }
}
```