# Java threadpool job queue items storage

Tags: java, multithreading, threadpoolexecutor

I have a threadpool with 20 threads and i want to add more tasks to my job queue. From the docs, i learn that i can use a blockingqueue to keep waiting for new jobs and to do them - [Create a Job Queue or Task Controller and dynamically add task to it in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41312981/create-a-job-queue-or-task-controller-and-dynamically-add-task-to-it-in-java)

I estimate i will have thousands of jobs to do and i could use some sort of a database to store the jobs and to keep polling the database for new jobs and adding them to the queue.

I have read of 'solutions' such as Jms,ActiveMQ,Redis and others but i do not know how they would help here.

Of much interest is:

1. Will those solutions poll for me the jobs storage and pass the job to the threadpool for me or will i have to write that part myself?.

Comment: Where do the jobs come from? Why do you think you need a database? What do you want to achieve? Let's say "thousands" is 100,000. Let's say each job stored in the queue needs 1KB of memory (to store its input data). You would thus need 100MB of memory, which is basically nothing these days.

Comment: The jobs are coming from the users actions like send activation email,welcome emails etc. I want to persists this requests in a db somewhere and process them later.

Comment: JMS would be helpful here: it can be transactional, and thus add a new job to a queue only if the transaction (like creating the user, etc.) succeeds. It can make the messages persistent and thus not lose a job if the server crashes or anything like that. And it can guarantee that the message is delivered only once and consumed transactionally (and thus avoid several welcome mails to be sent for the same job), and distribute the load over several nodes of your cluster.

Comment: Many thanks for your answer.